# Getting host name of client url in node.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

I am sending data from JavaScript client to node.js server using `XMLHttpRequest` ajax. Now on server side I need to know the host of URL of the page the JavaScript calling XMLHttpRequest is embedded in.

Server side:

```
req.on('data', function(data) {
  var d = JSON.parse(data);
  if (d.Type == "abc") {
    var host = req.headers.Host;
    var reply = {
      "hostname": host
    };
    console.log("hostname :" + host);
    response.end(JSON.Stringify(reply));
  }
});
```

Expected result on console:
       hostname: hostname

Actual result on console:
        hostname: undefined

Comment: Kindly [edit] the post to add the full code if you have.

Comment: What is the question ? What is not working as you expect it to work ?

Comment: What do you mean by "client's url". Clients don't have URLs! Do you mean the hostname of the computer the request is coming from? Do you mean the URL of the page the JavaScript calling XMLHttpRequest is embedded in? Something else?

Comment: Yes @Quentin, i mean "client's url" as the second option suggested by you, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers include a `Referer` HTTP Request header as normal for XHR requests. You can examine that.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin , referer works as var url=req.headers.referer gives full url and url.split("//")[2] gives domain name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const clientUrl = req.header('Referer');
console.log(clientUrl);
```